# how to make an animation in pygame

Tags: python, animation, pygame

i am trying to make an animation of when my player gets shot to make it seem like he is falling to the ground.

i have tried the code below but that doesn't seem to work. it slows down the frames and only shows the last image of my animation is there a simpler way of animation in pygame?

```
    if player2_hit_sequence == True:
        stage1 = True
        if stage1 == True:
            game_display.blit(dying1_p2, (player2X, player2Y))
            time.sleep(0.2)
            stage1 = False
            stage2 = True
        if stage2 == True:
            game_display.blit(dying2_p2, (player2X, player2Y))
            time.sleep(0.2)
            stage2 = False
            stage3 = True
        if stage3 == True:
            game_display.blit(dying3_p2, (player2X, player2Y))
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

is there a function to make a sequence of images or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so for animation you need a bunch of images, and a timer.

I'm presenting some code snippets based around a pygame sprite.  Maybe this doesn't exactly fit the question, but it seems like a better solution then painting/blitting images manually.

So first the code starts with a sprite class:

```
class AlienSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.base_image = pygame.image.load('alien.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.base_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )
        # Load warp animation
        self.warp_at_time = 0
        self.warp_images = []
        for filename in [ "warp1.png", "warp2.png", "warp3.png" ]:
            self.warp_images.append( pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha() )
```

So the idea is the Alien Sprite has a "normal" image, but then when it "warps" (teleports) an animation plays.  The way this is implemented is to have a list of animation images.  When the animation starts, the sprite's `image` is changed from `base_image` to the first of the `warp_images[]`.  As time elapses, the sprites image is changed to the next frame, and then the next, before finally reverting back to the base image.  By embedding all this into the sprite `update()` function, the normal updating mechanism for sprites handles the current "state" of the alien sprite, normal or "warp".  Once the "warp"-state is triggered, it runs without any extra involvement of the pygame main loop.

```
def update(self):
    # Get the current time in milliseconds (normally I keep this in a global)
    NOW_MS = int(time.time() * 1000.0)
    # Did the alien warp? (and at what time)
    if (self.warp_at_time > 0):
        # 3 Frames of warp animation, show each for 200m
        ms_since_warp_start = NOW_MS - self.warp_at_time
        if ( ms_since_warp > 600 ):
            # Warp complete
            self.warp_at_time = 0
            self.image = self.base_image  # return to original bitmap
            # Move to random location
            self.rect.center = ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), random.randrange( 0,  WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
        else:
            image_number = ms_since_warp // 200  # select the frame for this 200ms period
            self.image = self.warp_images[image_number] # show that image

def startWarp(self):
    # Get the current time in milliseconds (normally I keep this in a global)
    NOW_MS = int(time.time() * 1000.0)
    # if not warping already ...
    if (self.warp_at_time == 0):
        self.warp_at_time = NOW_MS
```

So the first thing to notice, is that the `update()` uses the clock to know the number of elapsed milliseconds since the animation started. To keep track of the time I typically set a global `NOW_MS` in the game loop.

In the sprite, we have 3 frames of animation, with 200 milliseconds between each frame.  To start a sprite animating, simply call `startWarp()` which obviously just kicks-off the timer.

```
SPRITES = pygame.sprite.Group()
alien_sprite = AlienSprite()
SPRITES.add(alien_sprite)

...

# Game Loop
done = False
while not done:
    SPRITES.update()

    # redraw window
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    SPRITES.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()

    if (<some condition>):
        alien_sprite.startWarp()  # do it
```

Obviously all those frame timings & what-not should be member variables of the sprite class, but I didn't do that to keep the example simple.